# why there is infinite recursion?

Tags: recursion

Given the following function definition, what value is returned by the call `dub(2.0, 4)`?

```
double dub(double z, int n) {
    if (z == 0) return z;
    return 2 * dub(z, n-1);
}
```

Comment: Spending 60 seconds in a debugger would make it quite clear. It would be a really great idea to learn how to use one, so you can figure these things out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

> what value is returned by the call `dub(2.0, 4)`?

It will not return, let alone return any value.

The reason is `z` never becomes `0`, so your base case condition never becomes true, hence the function never returns. So it gets called infinitely many times, which you have already seen as your title says. A recursive function ends when it reaches the base case, and in your situation the base case is never attained.

Read about recursion:

- [Programmers.stackexchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/25052/in-plain-english-what-is-recursion)
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science))

---

May be this is what you originally intended:

```
double dub(double z, int n) {
    if (n == 0) return z; // checking if n is 0, instead of z
    return 2 * dub(z, n-1);
}
```

Comment: @CynthiaGarcia You are welcome! If it helped you, mark it as accepted then (by clicking on the hollow tick next to the answer)! :) Accepting an answer increases your reputation too!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear are you asking "why is this function resulting in infinite recursion?" if so the reason is because you are checking the wrong value in the edge condition. the function should be written as so

```
double dub(double z, int n) {
  if (n == 0) return z;
  return 2 * dub(z, n-1);
}
```

noitice the conditional was changed to `n == 0` as opposed to `z == 0`

Comment: You may want to edit your formatting a little bit. Your ending brace is dangling :)

Comment: @Shadowfax good observation - the troubles of answering on mobile haha